# How do I add another div inside an existing div?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

`const newRules = [];`

I want to add:

```
<div className='cancel-fee-icon'/>
```

As a child element inside the below parent element:

```
newRules.push(<div className='cancel-fee' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(hotelPolicyInfo.CancellationPolicy)} />)
```

How do I add this?

Comment: I don't know about react... in js it would be a matter of selecting the existing parent element (if already existing in the dom, using querySelector for example) and doing `.append()` of the newly created element returned by `document.createElement()`. But that's not what you are asking for... someone else will better tell you the correct practice with react

Answer (score 1):

With this little context I can only think of doing something like this:

```
return (
  <div className='cancel-fee'>
    <div className='cancel-fee-icon'/>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` may work if I could know what is `hotelPolicyInfo.CancellationPolicy` like and where you want to insert div exactly.